# How can I add a legend to indicate a color code instead of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I am struggling to add a color code (legend) to the plot created with the PwrPlot() function shown below. This is for a teaching demonstration and I just need to replace the labels (alpha, beta, 1-alpha, 1-beta) by a legend indicating what each color refers to (indeed, changing the parameters of the curves could result in some 'ugly' label positions in the graph!). And running this function also gives out warnings that I can't interpret:

**Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) :
is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'**

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
    PwrPlot <- function(mu0=0, mu1=1.9, sig0=1, sig1=1, alpha=0.05, tail=1){
  ggplot(data.frame(x = -4:5), aes(x)) + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0), 5), fill = 'red') + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(-4, qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0)), fill = 'deepskyblue3') + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu1, sig1)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu1, sig1), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0), 5), fill = 'cyan4', alpha=0.2) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu1, sig1), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(-4, qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0)), fill = 'chocolate3', alpha=0.5) +

    geom_text(x=-0.4, y=0.18, label=expression(1-alpha), size=10, col="white") +
    geom_text(x=2, y=0.018, label=expression(alpha), size=10, col="white") +
    geom_text(x=1, y=0.1, label=expression(beta), size=10, col="white") +
    geom_text(x=2.5, y=0.1, label=expression(1-beta), size=10, col="black") +
    geom_text(x=-1.7, y=0.35, label="H0", size=10, col="black") +
    geom_text(x=3.5, y=0.35, label="H1", size=10, col="black") +
    labs(y="Densité") 
}
PwrPlot()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That solves this issue, and I can go forward!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the colours inside `aes()` and combined with `scale_fill_identity()` you can construct a legend.

```r
library(ggplot2)

PwrPlot <- function(mu0=0, mu1=1.9, sig0=1, sig1=1, alpha=0.05, tail=1){
  ggplot(data.frame(x = -4:5), aes(x)) + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0), 5), 
                  aes(fill = 'red')) + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(-4, qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0)), 
                  aes(fill = 'deepskyblue3')) + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu0, sig0)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu1, sig1)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu1, sig1), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0), 5), 
                  aes(fill = 'cyan4'), alpha=0.2) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = c(mu1, sig1), geom = 'area',
                  xlim = c(-4, qnorm(1-alpha/tail, mu0, sig0)),
                  aes(fill = 'chocolate3'), alpha=0.5) +
    scale_fill_identity(
      labels = expression(beta, 1-alpha, 1-beta, alpha),
      guide = guide_legend()
    ) +
    annotate(
      "text", size = 10,
      x = c(-0.4, 2, 1, 2.5, -1.7, 3.5),
      y = c(0.18, 0.018, 0.1, 0.1, 0.35, 0.35),
      label = expression(1-alpha, alpha, beta, 1-beta, "H0", "H1"),
      colour = rep(c("white", "black"), each = 3)
    ) +
    labs(y="Densité") 
}
PwrPlot()
#> Warning in is.na(x): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type
#> 'expression'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>